# How to update Model from partial after ajax file upload?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So I have ajax file upload partial (using [Jquery Form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) plugin), it's working perfectly, but I don't know to update model value after file uploading

```
<div>
   @Html.Partial("PhotoUpload", Model.Place)
</div>
```

Here I'm calling partial and giving to it part of a model.

```
@model PlaceMap.DAL.Entities.Place
@using (Html.BeginForm("PhotoUpload", "Place", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "photoUpload", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Image upload was unsuccessful")
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Photo)                                                                                                                                                                                  
        <input type="file" id="file" name="file"/>
        <input type="submit" id="sbm" />
    }
}
```

This is view code of partial, accepting model and form for uploading

```
var options = {
    url: "/Place/PhotoUpload",
    dataType: "json",
    clearForm: true,
    resetForm: true,
    success: showResponse
};

function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)
{
    $('#photo').append('<img src="/Images/Places/' + responseText.Photo + '" />');
}

$('#photoUpload').submit(function ()
{
    $('#photoUpload').ajaxSubmit(options);
    return false;
});
```

Javascript code for plugin

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PhotoUpload(string Photo, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                //some logic here
                return Json(new { Photo = filename });
            }

        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {

        }

        return PartialView();
    }
```

Controller action code. It's returning file name, it's going to js function "showResponse" and appending image to div. It's all work perfectly, but I have to write file name to @Model.Photo of this partial and I don't know how to do it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use `text/plain` from the server:

```
return Json(new { Photo = filename }, "text/plain");
```

and on the client manually parse:

```
function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
    var data = $.parseJSON(responseText);
    $('#photo').append('<img src="/Images/Places/' + data.Photo + '" />');
}
```

Obviously you lust remove the `dataType: 'json'` option for this to work.

Another possibility is to follow what's explained in the [documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload) and write a custom action result which will wrap your JSON response with the `<textarea>` tags:

> Browsers that support the XMLHttpRequest Level 2 will be able to
>   upload files seamlessly and even get progress updates as the upload
>   proceeds. For older browsers, a fallback technology is used which
>   involves iframes since it is not possible to upload files using the
>   level 1 implmenentation of the XMLHttpRequest object. This is a common
>   fallback technique, but it has inherent limitations. The iframe
>   element is used as the target of the form's submit operation which
>   means that the server response is written to the iframe. This is fine
>   if the response type is HTML or XML, but doesn't work as well if the
>   response type is script or JSON, both of which often contain
>   characters that need to be repesented using entity references when
>   found in HTML markup.
>
> To account for the challenges of script and JSON responses when using
>   the iframe mode, the Form Plugin allows these responses to be embedded
>   in a textarea element and it is recommended that you do so for these
>   response types when used in conjuction with file uploads and older
>   browsers. Please note, however, that if there is no file input in the
>   form then the request uses normal XHR to submit the form (not an
>   iframe). This puts the burden on your server code to know when to use
>   a textarea and when not to. If you like, you can use the iframe option
>   of the plugin to force it to always use an iframe mode and then your
>   server can always embed the response in a textarea. But the
>   recommended solution is to test for the 'X-Requested-With' request
>   header. If the value of that header is 'XMLHttpRequest' then you know
>   that the form was posted via ajax.

Comment: I think you misunderstood question. This code is working perfectly. I just need to add model updating logic in it. As you could see from partial view, it is strongly typed, so I need to put file name of uploaded file in @Model, I've tried to use ViewData and ViewBag, but no luck there.

Comment: From what I understood you want to fetch the photo filename that is returned by the server inside your `showResponse` method. I don't understand what you mean by updating a model. There's no longer a model. You are sending an AJAX request to the server.

Comment: If you look at first piece of code, you'll see that I'm passing model to this partial. This model I want to update.

Comment: But this model exists only when the page is first rendered. The AJAX request happens when the form is submitted. Talking about this model and that stage makes no sense. This model doesn't exist. Tha way AJAX works is that you send an asynchronous request to the server which could return different types of results: HTML partials, JSON, XML, ...

Comment: Okay, I got it. I will try another mechanism to save it. Session, for example. Thank you for answering.